# Creating summary aggregation on a drupal fullcalendar or calendar module view?

Tags: drupal-7, fullcalendar

In drupal 7, what would be the best way to change the base query to return a summary of items based on taxonomy terms (or any field).  Aggregation appears to not work on the calendar modules.  The fullcaendar module seems to not handle it at all and the calendar module seems to try but it doesn't work right.  I am familiar with module programming but am not very experienced at it so I would like to get some direction in what to override or hook into to manipulate the query to provide the results either module requires to support this and work within the existing modules logic.